# Using a JavaScript Map with array as key, why can't I get the stored value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, ecmascript-6

My code initializes a Map object and uses arrays as key.  When I try to use the map.get() method, I get "undefined" instead of the value I expect.  What am I missing?

```
const initBoardMap = () => {
  let theBoard = new Map()
  for (let r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
      //create a Map and set keys for each entry an array [r,c]
      //set the value to a dash
      // ---- commented out the array as key :-(
      //theBoard.set([r, c], '-')
      const mykeyStr = r + ',' + c
      theBoard.set(mykeyStr, '-')
    }
  }
  return theBoard
}

const printBoardMap = theBoard => {
  for (let r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
    let row=''
    for (let c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
      //initialize an array as the map key
      // comment out array as key
      // let mapKey = [r, c]
      //
      //why can't I get the value I expect from the line below?
      //
      //let square = theBoard.get(mapKey)
      //log the value of map.get --- notice its always undefined   
      const mykeyStr = r + ',' + c
      row += theBoard.get(mykeyStr)
       if (c < 2) row += '|'
    }
    console.log(row)
  }
}
let boardMap = initBoardMap()

printBoardMap(boardMap)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you pass in a non-primitive to `.get`, you need to have used `.set` with a reference to the *exact same object*. For example, while setting, you do:

```
  theBoard.set([r, c], '-')
```

This *creates* an array `[r, c]` when that line runs. Then, in `printBoardMap`, your

```
  let mapKey = [r, c]
```

creates *another* array `[r, c]`. They're not the same array; if `orig` were the original array, `mapKey !== orig`.

You might consider setting and getting strings instead, for example `'0_2'` instead of `[0, 2]`:

```
theBoard.set(r + '_' + c, '-')
```

and

```
const mapKey = r + '_' + c;
```

(best to use `const` and not `let` when possible - only use `let` when you need to reassign the variable in question)

Comment: Thanks CertainPerformance,  I seemed like it was a value vs reference issue.  I see that I can do it with a string.  Sure would be nice if I could use an array or object but seems there's no way to get random access to a Map entry unless the key is primitive?

Comment: Right, I suppose another way would be to create *another* `Map` that gets the (singular) `[r, c]` array from a `'#_#'` string, but that's only putting the same issue behind an unnecessary later of abstraction

Comment: I started by trying to deconstruct this redux code [https://github.com/DatGreekChick/tic-tac-toe] that uses _ immutable_ Map as the board data structure.  Ah now I see that sticks to primitive data types (Number) as key.  Ultimately it creates this:  
**Map { 0: Map { 0: "X", 1: "O", 2: "X" }, 2: Map { 0: "O", 1: "X", 2: "O" }, 1: Map { 0: "X", 1: "O", 2: "X" } }**